# Вывод каждого значения из листа json.loads()

Tags: python, json, парсер, requests

Необходимо получить каждый никнейм модератора. Как это можно сделать?

Код:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/online/staff")
r = r.content

print(r)

r = json.loads(r)

print(" Модераторы в сети:")

for x in r[0 + 1]['username']:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сервер возвращает JSON, то можно воспользоваться методом [r.json()](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

```
In [38]: r = requests.get("https://api.vime.world/online/staff")

In [39]: [x.get('username') for x in r.json()]
Out[39]:
['Bestbody',
 'DimanFeed',
 'denTASHER',
 'KawaiiJulia',
 'Luntik_B_GUCCI',
 'idlle']
```